# Elasticsearch- sum specific field in specific datetime range?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement of find sum one fields in a single query. I have managed to sum specific field in specific datetime range .
I try to use aggregation query to get the field total in specific datetime range,but get total value is 0

My document json look like the following way :

```
{
  "_index": "flow-2018.02.01",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2018-02-01T01:02:40.701Z",
    "dest": {
      "ip": "120.119.37.237",
      "mac": "d4:6d:50:21:f8:44",
      "port": 3280
    },
    "final": true,
    "flow_id": "EQQA////DP//////FP8BAAFw5CIXZxTUbVAh+ERn/7FMeHcl7S6z0Aw",
    "last_time": "2018-02-01T01:01:48.349Z",
    "source": {
      "ip": "100.255.177.76",
      "mac": "70:e4:30:15:67:14",
      "port": 45870,
       "stats": {
         "bytes_total": 60,
         "packets_total": 1
      }
    },
    "start_time": "2018-02-01T01:01:48.349Z",
    "transport": "tcp",
    "type": "flow"
  },
   "fields": {
    "start_time": [
      1517446908349
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      1517446960701
    ],
    "last_time": [
      1517446908349
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1517446960701
  ]
}
```

My search query :

```
    {
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
             {
               "range":{
                  "_source.@timestamp":{
                     "gte": "2018-02-01T01:00:00.000Z",
                     "lte": "2018-02-01T01:05:00.000Z"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "total":{
         "sum":{
            "field":"stats.packets_total "
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, `stats.packets_total` should be `source.stats.packets_total` (and make sure to remove the space at the end of the field name), like this:

```
    {
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
             {
               "range":{
                  "@timestamp":{
                     "gte": "2018-02-01T01:00:00.000Z",
                     "lte": "2018-02-01T01:05:00.000Z"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "total":{
         "sum":{
            "field":"source.stats.packets_total"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: hi Val, I have follow as you said to modify my query ,but aggregation s result still 0.0

Comment: Oh I see, you had another issue with the field in your range query, i.e. no need to specify `_source`. Try again

Comment: after remove _source and run again , but get the strange results :  "aggregations" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 6.555955481E9
    }
  }

Comment: the sum aggregations result shouldn't be decimals

Comment: It's not decimals, it's scientific notation and it boils down to `6555955481`